# apache cordova set/get audio name/path from storage

Tags: android, cordova

I want to be able to save the name and path of a recorded audio file, then get these values next time I start my app. I believe I can save them like this, to local storage:

```
// after recording is done
function captureSuccess(mediaFile) {
  addFilePath(mediaFile);
}

function addFilePath(mediaFile) {
    localStorage.setItem(mediaFile.name, mediaFile.fullPath);
}
```

How can I get these values the next time I start the app? are there a better way to store these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your way, when you will try to get the path of the audio file next time you can not know the key 'mediaFile.name'.

In my application, I created an object that contains the file's informations, then I stored it in localStorage using constant key like 'audio'. The following example illustrates how to do that:

```
var fileName = "audioFileName";
var filePath = "audioFilePath";

localStorage.myaudio = { name: fileName, path: filePath };


// to get file's informations in the next time
var audio = localStorage.myaudio;

var fileName = audio.name;
var filePath = audio.path;
```

If you want to store more than one file :

```
// get stored array in localStorage
audioFiles = localStorage.myaudio ? JSON.parse(localStorage.myaudio) : [];

// add new audio to array
var fileName = "audioFileName";
var filePath = "audioFilePath";
audioFiles.push({ name: fileName, path: filePath });

// store array in localStorage
localStorage.myaudio = JSON.stringify(audioFiles);
```

Comment: okey, but what if a user records another audio, will the first one be overwritten?

Comment: In this case you can create an array 'audioFiles' that contains all audio files then use localStorage.myaudio = JSON.stringify(audioFiles) to store the array in localStorage. If you want to read the array again use myArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.myaudio)

Comment: I was just about to ask you if it was possible maybe append to an array in storage, this helps a lot, thank you